# Best Way to manage String inside my asp.net mvc (comparison and check existence)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on an asp.net mvc web application, currently I am having some issues when dealing with strings, basically because of :-

1. Insert or edit values with white spaces in the begging and end.
2. Check the string uniqueness , when editing a  field.

For the first issue I have the following action method:-

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(DataCenter dc)
{
```

Where data center has a property named “Name”. Now if users insert values such as “ABC” and “ ABC  ”, they will be saved on the SQL server as two different values. Although I have defined a unique constrain on the database. So the best way I found to solve this is to modify my action method to be as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(DataCenter dc)
{
    dc.name = dc.name.trim();
    //…
}
```

But I ended up doing so on all the associated action methods and on the edit & create action methods.

*Question 1: Is there a better way to trim strings?*

Second issue, on the action method I was checking is the string is unique or not as follows, by writing a service method:-

```
if (!repository.IsDataCenterUnique(dc.Name))
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("Name", "Error occurred: DataCenter Name already exsists.");
}
```

But having this method inside an edit action method will cause an error in case the user edits the object but did not change its name. So I modified my service method to pass the object id, then I was excluding it from the comparison as follows:-

```
if (!repository.IsDataCenterUnique(dc.Name,dc.ID))
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("Name", "Error occurred: DataCenter Name already exsists.");
}

public bool IsDataCenterUnique(string name,int? id=0)
{
    return !tms.DataCenters.Any(a => a.Name.ToUpper() == name.ToUpper() && a.ID != id);
}
```

*Question 2: Is there a better way to solve this issue instead of passing the object id and excluding it?*

Comment: What database mapping library are you using?

Comment: i am using entity framework .

Answer (score 3):

Put an extension method on strings that will aliases a case-insensitive compare:

```
public static class StringExtensions {
    public bool TrimAndEqualsInsensitive (this string str1, string str2) {
        return str1.Trim().Equals(str2.Trim(), StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
    }
}
```

Then you can call `first.TrimAndEqualsInsensitive(second)` on the string you want to compare to the other.

You can also put a `[CustomValidation(Method="ValidationMethod")]` on your Id field in your model where `ValidationMethod` takes a string/id type that you will check the database for using `TrimAndEqualsInsensitive`, then you can check `.IsValid` before updating the database.

Comment: and what about trimming the strings prior to adding or editing the object ? is another antoher way to do so comparing to my current approach ?

Comment: Put a `[CustomValidation(Method="ValidationMethod")]` where `ValidationMethod` takes a string that you will check the database for using `TrimAndEqualsInsensitive`, then you can check `.IsValid` before updating the database.